# In Yu-Gi-Oh, when you banish cards from the field, can you banish spell and trap cards in addition to monster cards?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I have a [Eater of Millions](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Eater_of_Millions):

> Cannot be Normal Summoned/Set. Must be Special Summoned (from your hand) by banishing 5 or more cards from your hand, field and/or Extra Deck, face-down, and cannot be Special Summoned by other ways. This card gains 100 ATK and DEF for each face-down banished card. This face-up card on the field cannot be Tributed, nor used as Material for a Fusion, Synchro, or Xyz Summon. Once per turn, at the start of the Damage Step, if this card battles an opponent's monster: You can banish that opponent's monster, face-down.

Am I allowed to banish spells and traps from the field too?

Comment: Welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange! I added the text of the card for clarity about what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three [types of cards](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_type): Monster, Spell, and Trap. If one of these types are not specified, then it is assumed to be any of those types of cards. In this specific case, that means that Eater of Millions can indeed banish any type of card.

If you were only allowed to banish certain card types, it would be like [Bazoo the Soul-Eater](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Bazoo_the_Soul-Eater), which says that you banish "monsters" instead of "cards":

> Once per turn: You can banish up to 3 monsters from your Graveyard; this card gains 300 ATK for each, until the end of your opponent's turn.

This card would not be permitted to banish spell or trap cards.